# Sending a packet to different destinations in one time

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, udp, client-server

I'm working on a java project which must resist to failures on the server, so i need to send a single packet to different servers with different IPv4 addresses but at once, like a multicast.

Is there anyway to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is already a part of your question, use java.net.MulticastSocket
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html
Or have I misunderstood the question and you already know this solution, but you are looking for another way.

Comment: I don't have an ip address for the multicast, they are just different machines with different IPs, would it work with multicasting, if yes how ? Thanks.

Comment: No, you need to have an adress.
Do the clients know the ip of the server? If yes, the server could listen on a 'subscriber port' in an extra thead. The clients can subscribe the message by sending their ips and the ports the server should use to notfy the clients.